# Windows Store Apps Trouble Shooter does not Recognize that I am signed in

Tags: windows-10

I was trying to launch games that I have installed from the Microsoft/Xbox Store on Windows 10 Precision 5520 laptop and all of my Microsoft games gave an error when I launch them that I am not connected to the internet even though I am. So I thought maybe if I download the beta Xbox app and try to launch them from there it might work. So when I added the app to my download queue in the Microsoft App store, it hangs on "Acquiring Licenses" and then eventually goes to an error, the "more details" button shows that it is an error code: 0x80072ee2.

Through googling that I found some suggestions to try the "Windows Store Apps troubleshooter." When I try this is it will eventually stop on a screen asking me to sign in to a Microsoft account with a link to open the account settings. I click that and see that I am signed in. I tried signing out then back in. Nothing seems to work, help would be much appreciated, with my goal to be able to eventually launch my games again.

Comment: You need to ensure UAC is fully enabled to use the Microsoft Store. Have you enabled UAC?

Comment: UAC? User account control? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: UAC means User Account Control  Go to User Account Control settings (Control Panel, User Accounts, and Change User Account Control Settings) and ensure it is enabled

Comment: Ok, I do have User Accounts Control enabled.

Comment: "beta Xbox app" - Will is not compatible with the games you are trying to download unless they are also in Beta.

Comment: We might be thinking of different apps this is the app I was trying to download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xbox-beta/9mv0b5hzvk9z?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Answer (score 0):

For error 0x80072ee2, do two things:

1. Windows 10, Start, Settings, Apps, scroll down for Microsoft Store, Advanced, and reset the app. Restart and test.
2. If you are continuing to have issues, work through the corrective settings in the second answer post in the thread below:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-store-error-codes-0x80072ee2-and/422f7502-7c5b-43f9-b02a-d3e105387320

> Quote "Method 1: Reset the store cache by following the steps below
>   and check if the issue is resolved.
>
> Resetting Windows store will clear, and empty the cache without
>   changing account settings or deleting the installed apps. It is
>   usually located in the %SYSTEM% folder in the PC.
>
> Open Run command by pressing Windows Key + R. Type wsreset.exe and
>   press Enter. Open Windows Store and check if the app can now be
>   installed/purchased on your device.
>
> Method 2: If the issue persists, disable proxy settings by following
>   the steps below and check if the issue is resolved.
>
> Press Windows key + R keys on the keyboard, type inetcpl.cpl and press
>   Enter. Click on Connections tab and then click on LAN settings.
>   Uncheck the Use a proxy server for your LAN option. Click Apply. Close
>   the window open Windows Store and check if the changes are effective.
>
> Method 3: Create another administrator user account by referring to
>   Set up accounts on Windows 10 article and check if similar issue
>   persists.
>
> The corrupted user profile does not function normally such as not
>   launching Start menu, Cortana, Search bar, Store and other Windows
>   applications. In such cases creating a new profile and checking for
>   the same will help in identifying if the is specific to corrupted user
>   profile or the OS."

Added point:

If the above does not work, then you need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: none of these worked, but i am not having trouble with other windows apps, i can open news, weather, start menu etc, no problem. what else should i try?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the next step of a Windows 10 Repair Install.  That would be the next logical step on this error